# JSON with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am getting an error in MySql table field.

I tried to send JSON data from Postman to MySql with Spring Boot.

In the structure of this JSON, there is an array of values.

The problem is, when I get the values ​​in the MYSQL field which contains an array. It writes to me:

```
¬í ur [Ljava.lang.String; ÒVçé {G xp t.arrayValue1, arrayValue2
```

And on the Spring Boot console, I get a Warn:

```
2020-09-18 12: 05: 14.854 WARN 18384 --- [nio-8181-exec-5] .wsmsDefaultHandlerExceptionResolver: Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `[ Ljava.lang.String; `out of VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Ljava.lang.String;` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 22, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.glv.entities.Devis ["accessory"])]
```

The JSON format:

```
{
"accessory": ["arrayValue1", "arrayValue2"]
}
```

Spring Boot code :

```
private string[] accessory;

public void setAccessory(String[] accessory) {
        this.accessory = accessory;
```

I translated "accessories" into "accessory" so that it becomes understandable